# How to make TTTAttributedLabel align center programatically in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattritubedlabel

I am developing an app where I have a string that consists of tags with prefix #.

I am using TTTAttribute Label to add links to words which are having prefix # in a given string.

When I added links to TTTAttribute label. It successfully added and when clicking on that I am able to get that selected word having prefix # in that string..

But I was not able to align center the TTTAttribute label based on string length..

The default property

attributedLabel.verticalAlignment=TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;

is not working while applying links..I want the label align center based on its length as shown below..

[image: Label with single tag]

[image: Label with two tags]

[image: Label with three tags]

If it is normal TTTAttribute label without applying links then default align property is applying correctly..

Here is the code I used for adding links..

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSRange matchRange;
        NSString *tweet = @"#MYTWEET ,#tweet, #fashion #Share";

        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tweet];
        if (![scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:nil]) {
            // there is no opening tag
        }
        NSString *result = nil;
        if (![scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&result]) {
            // there is no closing tag
        }
        //@"theString is:%@",result);


        NSArray *words = [tweet componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

      TTTAttributedLabel *attributedLabel=[[TTTAttributedLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 200, 320, 40)];

      attributedLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        attributedLabel.text=tweet;

        words = [tweet componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",0123456789`~!@$%^&*()_-+=.></?;:'* "]];

        for (NSString *word in words)
        {
            if ([word hasPrefix:@"#"])
            {
                //@"word %@",word);

                // Colour your 'word' here
                 matchRange=[tweet rangeOfString:word];

                [attributedLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:word] withRange:matchRange];

                [tagsarray addObject:word];
            }

        }

        attributedLabel.delegate=self;

       }

    - (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
       //@"result ==== %@",url);

        NSString *webString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];

        NSString *tagstring = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"Tag String is:%@",tagstring);

        }
```

I don't want to resize the frames of TTTAttribute label..

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple, use the following code:

```
attributedLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: You were definitely made some mistake there. It worked for me, it is fully tested. Please put some code or debug it yourself.

Comment: @Parcs..I posted entire code in my view controller. Please send some code or sample link which you have done...I am trying to fix this issue for so many days..Its needed to release my app...

Comment: Write this code, where you are creating the label:  TTTAttributedLabel *attributedLabel=[[TTTAttributedLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 200, 320, 40)]; attributedLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

Comment: @Parcs....I added your code but it does not aligned center. If I put comments at
 [attributedLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:word] withRange:matchRange];

this code then its working.

Why its behavior changed I dont know...

Comment: This actually worked just fine for me - not sure why it has not for others.

Answer (score 16):

You need to set the link attributes with the paragraph style set:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* attributeStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
attributeStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:11], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.324 green:0.0 blue:0.580 alpha:1.0], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:attributeStyle};

[self.atributedLabel setLinkAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: Note: You must be set the link attributes before the `addLinkToURL:withRange:` is called. Thanks!

Comment: This should no longer be necessary.  [I fixed this bug in January, 2015 and now links properly inherit the source paragraph style.](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/commit/fa654b579f23cf1715bca384a266ad8c4a0e20b7)