# How to make TTTAttributedLabel vertically align center with truncated tail

Tags: ios, uilabel, vertical-alignment, tttattributedlabel

I am using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to display some text vertically centered (default in both `TTTAttributedLabel` and `UILabel`), with a single line (also default), and truncated tail line breaking.

```
TTTAttributedLabel *label1 = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 40.0, 200.0, 60.0)];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
label1.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:label1];

TTTAttributedLabel *label2 = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 120.0, 200.0, 60.0)];
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
label2.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:label2];

NSString *shortString = @"This is a short string.";
NSString *longString = @"This is a somewhat longer string. In fact its really long. So long it takes up alot of space.";

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]};

NSMutableAttributedString *shortAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:shortString attributes:attributes];
label1.attributedText = shortAttributedString;

NSMutableAttributedString *longAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:longString attributes:attributes];
label2.attributedText = longAttributedString;
```

The above code renders the following:

[image]

The only difference for the two labels is the string length. As you can see, the second string is not centered vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350271/how-to-make-tttattributedlabel-align-center-programatically-in-ios), you need to set the paragraph style `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`:

```
TTTAttributedLabel *label1 = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 40.0, 200.0, 60.0)];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
label1.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:label1];

TTTAttributedLabel *label2 = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 120.0, 200.0, 60.0)];
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
label2.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:label2];

NSString *shortString = @"This is a short string.";
NSString *longString = @"This is a somewhat longer string. In fact its really long. So long it takes up alot of space.";

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0],
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

NSMutableAttributedString *shortAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:shortString attributes:attributes];
label1.attributedText = shortAttributedString;

NSMutableAttributedString *longAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:longString attributes:attributes];
label2.attributedText = longAttributedString;
```